# Can I prevent TStringlist removing key value pair when value set to empty

Tags: delphi

Can I prevent TStringList from removing key-value-pair when value is set to empty? I use Delphi XE8 and Lazarus which work differently. I want the pair to be left in the TStringlist object even when the value is set to an empty string. For example:

```
procedure TMyClass.Set(const Key, Value: String);
begin
  // FData is a TStringList object
  FData.Values[Key] := Value; // Removes pair when value is empty. Count decreases and Key is lost.
end;
```

Problem that I'm having is that when I compile with Delphi the pair with empty values is removed and I don't know afterwards was a value with a key never set or was it explicitly set to be an empty string. Also I can't get all the keys that have been used. Now I need to hold another collection of keys that holds information about empty ones.

```
MyKeyValues.Set('foo', 'bar'); // Delphi FData.Count = 1; Lazarus FData.Count = 1
MyKeyValues.Set('foo', '');    // Delphi FData.Count = 0; Lazarus FData.Count = 1
```

Comment: Embarcadero again... Weird, non-documented (at least in the german docs) behaviour. I wasted an hour looking for this "bug" in a big project. And they don't even implement a switch to change the behaviour...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write a [class helper](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Class_and_Record_Helpers_(Delphi)) to implement a new behaviour of the `SetValue` method of the `TStrings` class.

If you don't like a solution based on a class helper, you can use a custom class which inherits from `TStringList` and, again, override its `Values` property behaviour - the code is very similar to this helper-based implementation.

I'd prefer to use the second choice because the helper will define a new behaviour for all the `TStringList` objects.

```
type
  TStringsHelper = class helper for TStrings
    private
      function GetValue(const Name: string): string;
      procedure SetValue(const Name, Value: string); reintroduce;
    public
      property Values[const Name: string]: string read GetValue write SetValue;
  end;


function TStringsHelper.GetValue(const Name: string): string;
begin
  Result := Self.GetValue(Name);
end;

procedure TStringsHelper.SetValue(const Name, Value: string);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  I := IndexOfName(Name);
  if I < 0 then I := Add('');
  Put(I, Name + NameValueSeparator + Value);
end;
```

Comment: I also think that a derived class would suit best. Then we can get both Lazarus and Delphi code working the same way by changing the Values behaviour in the derived class and start using derived class and then leave TStrings behaviour as it is if someone needs that behaviour later. I noticed there's also limitaton on what keys you can use and that depends on the NameValueSeparator property. If you set kv['foo=bar'] := 'baz' then kv['foo'] is now 'bar=baz'. In the derived class I can also prevent use of keys that have NameValueSeparator in them.

Comment: FWIW I don't like *helpers* so much: I've only used them once, with some legacy code I couldn't fix in a different way. A derived class is quite always a more suitable solution in my opinion. I didn't know about keys limitation but have you already considered to use a [TDictionary](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/System.Generics.Collections.TDictionary)? It might suit your needs when dealing with key/value pairs and it should be faster than a `TStringList`

Comment: Yes I have considered TDictionary but we are not allowed to use that because the version of Lazarus we are using does not have that language feature. And I yes I agree TString.Values has poor performance because the search time grows linear when you add pairs. In my case the performance is not a problem because I have so few elements. I don't know if setting Sorted property true helps finding keys faster. The documentation on both Delphi and Lazarus is lacking in this area too.

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
procedure TMyClass.Set(const Key, Value: String);
var
  i:integer;
begin
  i := FData.IndexOfName(Key);
  if i = -1 then
    FData.Add(Key + '=' + Value)
  else
    FData[i] := Key + '=' + Value;
end;
```

You can choose wether to set `FData.Sorted:=true;` or not.

Answer (score 0):

`TStringList` doesn't have an option for that. Its behaviour is to delete an entry, when the value is empty (`''`).

You could implement that behaviour on you own by, for example, adding something like a prefix to your value:

```
procedure TMyClass.Set(const Key, Value: String);
begin
  FData.Values[Key] := '_' + Value;
end;
```

But that means, you also need a getter, to remove it again:

```
function TMyClass.Get(const Key): String;
begin
  Result := StringReplace(FData.Values[Key], '_', '', []);
end;
```